# Best way to scrape text from document?

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am trying to find the best way to scrape text from an HTML document directly to a .txt file. As I understand, this cannot be done with strictly Javascript but rather in Node.js. I also attempted a process in Python with BeautifulSoup but it may be above my level. The HTML document in question uses 'ng-bind' classes which didn't seem to mesh well with what I was trying to do.

I expect to pull a string of text out of an HTML document, directly to a .txt file.

Comment: Can you send me the link of the webpage you are trying to scrape ??

Comment: You can try [GoogleChrome/puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

Comment: The webpage is here: https://www.electionreturns.pa.gov/ I am trying to pull the candidate names, and eventually votes/vote % for a .txt file that will be used to populate a live crawl on television

Answer (score 1):

Try this python code and just put your own tag which you need to scrape from the website

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Text File where the content will be written
file = open("test.txt","w")

#Url from where the data will be extracted
urls ="https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python"
page = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('p'): #extracting all content of <P> tag from the url
    #You can put the desired tag according to your need
 file.write(link.get_text())  
file.close()
```